# UIScrollView inside UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm with a project in which I have a UIScrollView inside a UIView. Inside the UIScrollView has to see a list of buttons in 3 columns and X rows. I have the code that displays the buttons, but does not inserted into the UIScrollView, it prints over and does not scroll. Besides this, also cover the TabBar I have in the bottom of the view.

The code of the function that displais the buttons is

```
for (int y_axis=0; y_axis<=3; y_axis++)
    {
        for (int x_axis=0; x_axis<=2; x_axis++)
        {

            UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16+100*x_axis,100.0+115*y_axis,88.0 ,88.0)];
            btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];
            [self.view addSubview:btn];

        }
    }
```

How can I do to display this in the UIScrollView? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a UIScrollView scroller, you have to change your last line to this;

```
[self.scroller addSubview:btn];
```

If not, you are adding it to the view, and not the scroller. Also, you have to change the scrollers contentsize, which is the X*Y if how much it contains. For it to contain the whole screen and nothing more;

```
[self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)]
                                         ^     ^
```

Replace that with the width and the height you want to scroll. Each time you add a button below your new buttons, you should update the contentsize.

Comment: it works, but modifying in your first line self.scroller to scroller. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are adding buttons on view `[self.view addSubview:btn];` not on `ScrollView`. Try to make a view with all you buttons. and set your view with buttons as `contentview` of your `scrollview` .

Answer (score 1):

first you need the `UIScrollViewDelegate` in your .h file and then also check buttons are subview of yourScrollView or not also you add this button in your scrollview with code like this bellow...

```
[yourScrollView addSubview:yourbuttonname];
```

after that in your viewDidLoad method declare contentsize of your scrollview like this...

```
yourScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, anyheight);///here define height which you want to scroll the view...
```

hope this help you....
:)

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

```
    for loop
    {
        create buttons along with the desired frames;
        add those buttons to scrollview;
    }
    set the content size of the scrollview according to no of rows;
    add the scroll view to main view i.e. self.view;
```